# Upgrade to 22.04 Boots Only to BIOS

Tags: boot, upgrade, bios

Today I upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 and there were no errors with a completely smooth upgrade. However, upon rebooting, it goes directly to the system’s BIOS with no option to do otherwise. This is NOT a dual boot system and has only Ubuntu. How do I make it boot properly?

Comment: It may be useful if you could take a picture of the "BIOS" screen and add it to your question.

Comment: I don't think I ever heard of a system directly going to BIOS as that would require pressing a key like ESC, F2, F9, F10  or F12. The GRUB rescue prompt is more likely  so yes is there a way to post a picture? Post the link to it into the question  (imgur) and someone will edit the picture to show

Comment: I used to build, configure and sell PCs so I certainly know what the BIOS looks like and that’s what I’m getting but I have never seen such a thing happening either. I didn’t even know it was possible and none of the key presses will boot to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to load a live image onto a USB, and use the live USB to recover any important data. Then perform a stock re-installation with the live USB.

Depending on your comfort level with the terminal you could go into recovery mode in Ubuntu using the shift key (further instructions are a quick google search away)and perform a recovery in Ubuntu from there.

If you've experienced this before you may also want to look into using Pop!_OS. Most of Ubuntu's tutorials will work and you have a built in recovery partition. The recovery partition in Pop OS differs in that it uses a graphical method to restore your machine. I've had similar experiences in Pop OS and used the built in recovery mode to perform a factory restore. This is handy if you don't have a second computer to make a current live USB with or just don't want to mess with making one.

Comment: What information is missing from the post to warrant a down-vote?

Comment: A little difficult making a boot USB stick without the PC working.

Comment: Desktop, laptop? If so what make / model, and what is not factory, what add ons? Does that BIOS still list the hard drive? Does your BIOS have a maintenance mode that can test system and drive? Is you drive internal, external, eSATA, USB, SATA, HDD, or NVME? Did you change secure boot, legacy mode, SATA mode or other UEFI/BIOS seeings?     Let us know all the answers, or if this gets you on the right track to a solution.

Comment: Did you try the instructions for doing all of this from the terminal? It can be destructive and doing so can result in unsaved data being lost. I can post a link to some instructions on performing the task from the terminal, but again, highly probable unsaved data will be lost. Could you make a bootable USB from a friend, family member or even a work computer? That's the best option for a non destructive solution.

Comment: I can't get to anything but the BIOS so no, I did not try the instructions for doing all this from terminal as I cannot get to terminal. I do not have a laptop and am retired, located very rurally with no computer stores within an hour's drive. The PC is an Acer Veriton with Intel i7 CPU and has been running Ubuntu for quite a while with no problems. The BIOS does show the hard drive which is an internal 1TB eSATA. The BIOS has no UEFI settings that I can find, at least not under that name. I may have to format and install to an old external drive, boot to it, then run Boot Repair from there.

Comment: That sounds like a solid plan if you have the ability to install to your old external drive. Based off of your initial post and your subsequent answers I'm beginning to wonder if GRUB or whatever MBR you're using got damaged somehow. You mentioned you used to build and configure PC's. Do you have an old bootable drive laying around you could use to run a S.M.A.R.T. test on the boot drive and see the health of the drive?

Comment: I might have one from then but it would be “vintage” IDE. However, I should have some more recent old drives too that are eSATA although whether any have Ubuntu is another story. Still, even if Windows, I should be able to do something.

Comment: I finally found an old drive with an earlier version of Ubuntu installed and with it in a drive "toaster" connected through the external eSATA port, it is now repaired. Even though I could not seem to switch to the boot menu at boot time, the system found it and booted to it itself. With it finally booted to Ubuntu, I was able to create a Boot Repair USB stick which when booted and the appropriate selections made seemed to fix the problem.